# How can I solve this error? Error : variable lengths differ

Tags: r

I am trying to create a two boxplots side by side. I created a separate variable outside of my data frame. then I used the below codes.

```
boxplot(group_1$Catholic ~ group_2$Catholic)
```

But I get this error:

> Error in stats::model.frame.default(formula = group_1$Catholic ~
>   group_2$Catholic) :    variable lengths differ (found for
>   'group_2$Catholic')

Comment: Check the length of your data. I think the length of `group_1$Catholic` is not equal to `group_2$Catholic`.

Comment: I know their lengths are different. But this is what it is and I can not do anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using the formula method (eg. `group_1$Catholic ~ group_2$Catholic`).  The formula method is when you want to group the first vector into different categories by the second vector, for which length does matter. Thus, your vectors should be fed as arguments to `boxplot` as a `list` (eg. `boxplot(x=list(group_1$Catholic, group_2$Catholic))`.  A reproducible example:

```
a <- rnorm(n=50)
b <- rnorm(n=100)
boxplot(x=list(a, b))
```